# How to identify possible causes for screen not working?

Tags: screen, hardware, broken-screen

My Google Pixel 5a's screen has stopped working. When connected via [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy), the display is transmitted. Before ordering a new screen, I want to ask a couple of questions:

Could the problem be related to any other module?
Is it possible to identify the problematic module through ADB?

Comment: If your phone is bootloader locked you can try to check all the logs (adb logcat) you can get to see what errors it contains. But without any experience with a dead display you will have to interpret the errors yourself if it indicates a display error or not. https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-take-logs-android/